# cropping an image using ellipse shape in windows phone 8 application?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to crop my image using ellipse shape.I'll able to do that with rectangle but for ellipse not able to do.

```
    void ClipImage()
    {
        EllipseGeometry geo = new EllipseGeometry();

        r = (Ellipse)(from c in LayoutRoot.Children where c.Opacity == .5 select c).First();
        GeneralTransform gt = r.TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
        Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        geo.Rect = new Rect(p.X, p.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
        image1.Clip = geo;
        r.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

        TranslateTransform t = new TranslateTransform();
        t.X = -p.X;
        t.Y = -p.Y;
        image1.RenderTransform = t;
    }
```

r is ellipse and p is

```
 GeneralTransform gt = ((Ellipse)sender).TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
 Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Comment: i get error in this line geo.Rect = new Rect(p.X, p.Y, r.Width, r.Height);

Comment: i dont know what should i implement apart from rect

Comment: It's not really clear. Why the Visibility.Collapsed;and Transforms?  Better create a small but complete app and post that code.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth using an `ImageBrush` instead. You don't need to clip your image.

```
<Ellipse ... >
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="..."/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: i need croping beacuse i want to show  the image portion which i want to crop on to next page of my application